# Holzapfel-Gasser-Ogden (HGO) model

Tags: solid-mechanics, multiphase-flow, porous-medium

Can Holzapfel-Gasser-Ogden (HGO) model be applied to solid porous materials such as rocks, concrete and etc. as well? If yes, would you please introduce a reference.

If not, is there any modified version of Holzapfel-Gasser-Ogden (HGO) that can be applied to porous media like rocks?

Comment: What references do you have already? Otherwise people waste time duplicating stuff and you reply “already seen that” etc

Comment: Actually there is no particular reference except the main paper with more than 3400 citations. So everyone who is familiar with the question, for sure would know about this paper as the reference.
"A new constitutive framework for arterial wall mechanics and a comparative study of material models "
Gerhard A. Holzapfel,
Thomas C. Gasser, Ray W. Ogden
 at this link: https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1010835316564

Comment: The HGO model is designed for large deformation anisotropic elasticity.  While it could, after some convolutions with the parameters, be used for pressure-dependent elastoplastic materials such as rocks under monotonic loading, there are better models for these materials that have been designed specifically for them.

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer. According to the guidelines that you kindly explained, is it possible to recommend a reference that have applied the modified version of HGO to a rock or concrete?